# How to create a new file if an existing one already exists?

Tags: java, loops, new-operator, infinite, createfile

I was wondering if it was possible to create a method that would check if the current file exists, and if it does, then it creates a new file with the same name but +1. Eg. file, file1,file2,file3.

This needs to happen even if my application crashes. Currently im using this

```
Path = xxxxxxx;
index=0;
int index = 0;
    File myFile = new File(Path);
    if(!myFile.exists()){
    myFile.createNewFile(); 
    }

    else
    {
    index++;
     this.resultPath = xxxxxxx + index;
    }
```

This is always returning an infinate loop since my app crashes ( it's supposed to ) and index just gets restarted back to 0 and the loop checks for index=0 infinately. Any help would be appreciated ty.

Answer (score 2):

This is not strictly an Android question, so this goes for any similar Java code.

If you expect to have more than one file, get a list of the files in the 
directory and iterate to find the biggest number. Something like:

```
File myDir = new File("myDir");
String[] files = myDir.list();
```

You can also pass a filter to list() if you have other files in the 
directory as well.

Alternatively, if those files are temporary, and the actual file name 
doesn't matter much, you could use File.createTempFile(). It will 
automatically assign a unique name. You can specify a prefix and suffix 
so that you an identify the files.